# Could not use ipfs.add() to upload image to ipfs

Tags: javascript, svelte, ipfs

I am trying to upload an image to `ipfs` in my svelte app. This is the code where I try to upload the image:

```
const uploadFile = async (file) => {

    const ipfs = await IPFS.create();

    const result = await ipfs.add(file);
    console.log(result)
}
```

`file` is in `ArrayBuffer` format.

However, it returns the error saying:

```
(8) index.js:54 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: callback is not a function
    at Function../node_modules/peer-info/src/index.js.PeerInfo.create (index.js:54)
    at GossipSub._onIncomingStream (index.js:174)
    at Upgrader._onStream (upgrader.js:313)
    at Mplex.onStream (upgrader.js:235)
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can try adding the file by using ipfs.add in a for loop:

```
for await (const result of ipfs.add(file)) {
    console.log(result);
}
```

More info here: https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/blob/master/docs/core-api/FILES.md#add

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Mionutm!!

That was helpful. The problem was the `file`was not in the right format. I thought `ipfs` expects an `ArrayBuffer`so I read the `file` into `ArrayBuffer` format.

However, we could have added the uploaded file to ipfs just by accessing its property as follow:

```
const file = e.srcElement.files[0];
for await (const result of ipfs.add(file)) {
    console.log(result);
}
```

That solved the `add <suspended>` and the `invalid content` errors.

Nonetheless, the `TypeError: callback is not a function` is still unsolved, which i think it is the error produce by the node_modules (not sure).